# In a free group $F_n$, $n\geq 2$, all conjugacy classes except that of the identity are infinite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Let $F_n$ be a free group on n generators, $n\geq 2$. Studying a paper, I came across this sentence:

> In $F_n$, all conjugacy
>   classes except that of the identity are infinite

while I do not know how he claims it.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to know is that elements of the free group are presented by free words without relations other than $a^{-1} a= 1$ and $a a^{-1}=1$.

Say you have two generators $a,b$, than a typical words look like this:
$$x=a b a^{-1} b b b a^{-1} b^{-1} a.$$
This word cannot be further simplified (reduced).

Now it is plausible that the words
$$A:=a x a^{-1}, B:=ab x b^{-1} a^{-1},....$$
are all different, because otherwise the "difference" $A B^{-1}$ of two such words $A,B$ could be reduced to the empty words = the identity element.

Try it by examples, than you see how it goes.

Comment: "...without other relations than $\;a^{-1}a=aa^{-1}=a$ ...and all other relations that follow from group theory axioms"

Answer (score -1):

If $x\in F_n$, then the conjugacy class of $x$ is in bijection with the set of cosets of $C_{F_n}(x)$ in $F_n$ where $C_{F_n}(x)$ denotes the centralizer of $x$.

***Exercise***: $C_{F_n}(x)$ is infinite cyclic for all nonidentity $x\in F_n$. (*Hint*: subgroups of free groups are free.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Okay, so you are appealing to the fact that $|F_n : C_{F_n}(g)| = |\mathcal{K}(g)|$. But $C_{F_n}(g)$ being infinite doesn't necessarily guarantee that $|F_n : C_{F_n}(g)|$ is infinite, right?

Comment: @user193319 yes, but since $n\geq 2$, $C_{F_n}(g)$ being $\textit{infinite cyclic}$ implies that $|F_n:C_{F_n}(g)|$ is infinite.

Comment: Does this mean that there are infinite conjugacy classes in $F_n$, $n\geq 2$?

Comment: @user8253417 Thanks for your message! The argument I gave shows that the conjugacy class of each non-identity element of $F_n$ is infinite. However, there are also infinitely many conjugacy classes in $F_n$ for each $n\geq 2$. The argument is that the map $s:F_n\to \mathbb{Z}$ which computes the exponent sum of a word in $F_n$ is a class function (i.e., constant on conjugacy classes). Since $s$ is surjective, this proves that there are infinitely many conjugacy classes.